# How to calculate Windows Forms DataGrid content's size?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, size

I've got a datagrid filled with fixed data (non-database). There is no need to scroll the data itself and I want to set the size of the grid, such that all the data is visible (and no scrollbars are displayed). How can I calculate appropriate width and height?